# inserting data from a dynamic form into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I currently have a large form in which i need to to store the data in. the problem i have is the form isn't static and can become larger, for example the user could have 1++ addresses.

The current table consists of id,form_id,value and field as columns. i can currently add the value from the form, however how do i create a unique identifier to know what to field is situated too.

```
  $surname = isset($_POST['surname'][0]) ? $_POST['surname'][0] : '';
  $address1 = isset($_POST['address1'][0]) ? $_POST['address1'][0] : '';
  $address2 = isset($_POST['address2'][0]) ? $_POST['address2'][0] : '';
  $address3 = isset($_POST['address3'][0]) ? $_POST['address3'][0] : '';
```

Then push these all into an array.

```
    foreach ($applicant as $value) {
        //statement to insert data
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO applicant1(form_id,value)VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $formid);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
    $stmt->execute();

    }
```

How can i get the name of the field it came from or is there a different approach?

Comment: IDK what your plan with it is but perhaps you could store the form data as JSON and decode it when you need it?

Comment: @andyHolmes I have conditional logic, for example the applicant may have 1,2,3 or 100 cars(would be impressive/expensive if they did) so i need the database to be to store data dependent. would i create a separate table just for the car(make,year,price).

Comment: But what will you be doing with the data? Because I'm assuming you won't be creating extra table columns for *every* person who submits the form? Personally I would use JSON for blocks of the form, so you could have a car object that would have however many cars in it which could then be stored in a `cars` column and decoded when required

Comment: You could also have an object for addresses, to me this would keep your database a lot cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You should create a database with two tables,
Submission id who submitted the data with some information needed to get that row.
That table should have a pk primary key that is auto incremental.
The next table should be designed for what your gonna have multiple submissions of as well as any extra data you may want to collect. then it should have an fk Foreign key that is the primary key of the first table thus linking back to the original submission. if you were using ajax and wanted to do this all in real-time upon new address you would return the pk of that row from the second table you just submitted and put it in a custom xml attribute to the element. Like data-fk then you could grab that fk if you need to do something else in real-time without reloading the page.